# ChipGroup ChipChanged Listener is not working

Tags: android, chips

I have a chip group and have bunch of chips inside that particular group. I applied setOnCheckedChangeListener

```
private fun prefDialog(context: Context): Dialog {
        val dialog = Dialog(context)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pref_dialog)
        val chipGroup = dialog.findViewById<ChipGroup>(R.id.genre_chip_group)
        chipGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
            when (checkedId) {
                R.id.popChip -> Log.i(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: checked")
            }
        }
        return dialog
    }
```

but it's not being triggered. Kindly guide me how to achieve this

Comment: Can you please add code for `pref_dialog` layout and `popChip` ?

Comment: checkedId is not return view id but a num random for chips (like 7,8,9 for 2 chips)